# What was the shortest PhD thesis in physics?

Tags: soft-question, history

When I took freshman physics in 1983, my professor made an off-handed comment that Louis de Broglie's PhD thesis on the matter wave was only 3 pages long, and that it was the shortest PhD thesis ever in physics.

For some time now I've been trying to find a PhD of the thesis, which I presume is in German. I can't find it.

I have found the proper reference to his doctoral thesis, though. It appears to be:

> L. de Broglie, “Recherches sur la théorie des quanta”, Thèse de doctorat soutenue à Paris, le 25 novembre 1924, Annales de Physique (10e série) III (1925) 22. Reproduced in: L. de Broglie, Recherches sur la théorie des quanta (Fondation Louis de Broglie, Paris, 1992).

I've searched online for that document, and I can't find it. [I can find another publication with the same title](https://www.gsjournal.net/Science-Journals/Historical%20Papers-Quantum%20Theory%20/%20Particle%20Physics/Download/1635), but it appears to be a book based on the PhD thesis, and not the thesis itself.

So what is the shortest PhD thesis in physics, and if it is de Broglie's, where can I find it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about publication lengths rather than physics.

Comment: It does not look like de Broglie's thesis was 3 page long. According to American Journal of Physics 44, 1047 (1976), "De Broglie's thesis was published in its entirety in Ann. Phys. (Paris) 3, 22 ( 1925)." This publication's reprint can be found at https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00006807/document and it is about 80 page long.

Comment: @Qmechanic, this question is about the practice of physics. There is no physics without scientific publications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not really answering your question but perhaps you'll find this amusing: In 1951, a two-sentence, three-line paper was published in Physical Review by Friedrich Lenz who simply noticed that the (present) proton-electron mass ratio of $1836.12\pm 0.05$ happened to coincide with $6\pi^5=1836.12.$ You can find the article [here](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRev.82.554.2), or for those without access [here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lUaj.png).

Comment: Thanks for such an informative answer. It has given me so much hope that Physics and Maths aren't just for geniuses. I'm really grateful to you.

Comment: The Lenz case shows that some physicists, and journal editors, find numerology irresistible. Lens had absolutely no reason for thinking this ratio *ought* to be that value, and it isn’t.

Comment: That is totally cool. Thanks.

Comment: The Lenz article was fun, but the relationship no longer holds. Alas.